# Implementing jQuery into HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I'm following the CSS Tricks slideshow tutorial [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/), and I can't seem to figure out how to implement the jQuery portion of the tutorial. I've tried putting the code in between script elements but no luck. Any idea on how I can address the issue? Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? have you included [jQuery library](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js) in your project

Comment: @ArunPJohny I haven't! This is my first experience using the framework. I should include it in the head correct?

Comment: Yep. In something like a `<script src="/jquery.js"></script>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it like this in your page (you can add it in the head, or at the end of your body tag):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  3000);

    });
</script>
```

You didn't provide a lot of information, but I think you're not loading jQuery correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

anywhere before this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  3000);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need import jQuery library to your html file, place this in the header :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After, place your css code in your css file, and after place your html code in your file.